# Running Spark Applications Using IPython and Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: hadoop, pyspark

I'm trying to install Jupyter using [these instructions](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/spark_ipython.html).

I've have installed under Anaconda and when I try to run pyspark (from section 
Starting a Notebook with PySpark) I receive the following error:

> $ pyspark Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File"/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/jupyter", line 4, in 
>   from jupyter_core.command import main ImportError: No module named
>   jupyter_core.command

Comment: $ pyspark
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/jupyter", line 4, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command

Comment: if you type `jupyter notebook` in the terminal does it open jupyter?

Comment: No, Command not found

Comment: Is using cloudera an absolute must?

Comment: We are using Cloudera Parcels and Installed Anaconda, followed Installing and Configuring Jupyter in the documentation

Comment: if you navigate to `/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/` and type `jupyter notebook` does it work?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a script in a specific directory and execute will login to jupyte with pyspark

## !/bin/bash

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --NotebookApp.open_browser=False --NotebookApp.ip='*' --NotebookApp.port=8880"
export PATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin:$PATH
pyspark

go to http://host-name:8880/